# Login failed for user 'masteruser'

Tags: azure, paas, sql-database

I was moving my Sitecore 9.2 QA database in UAT in Azure PaaS. I have moved the web & master database and renamed the databases to UAT's database name.

In connectionString.config we have changed the database user's password.

But using the same user name & password I can login into SSMS, but the same username/password is not working in Sitecore connectionsting.config.

Can anyone highlight what else do we need to do for a DB change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the SQL management studio you will need to connect to the database server, and then run the below command to modify the password for DB users to one you specified in connectionstring.config. You will need to run this for all DB users specified in the connectionstring.config file (following is an example for "securityuser").

ALTER USER securityuser WITH PASSWORD = 's!tec0re'

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. The fix was to execute `sp_addrolemember` procedure with `'db_owner'` abd `'masteruser'` parameters like that:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'masteruser';
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix that you can do the following:

1. Login to SMSS with your SA
2. Navigate to the security/user as shown in the image below
3. [image: SMSS security]
4. Double click on the desired username
5. Go to the General Tab and modify the password to match the one provided with the one from the connectionstring (as shown below)
6. [image: List item]

   Hope this helps!

Comment: I am login with the particular user only with the password provided in config in SSMS. It is getting logged in. No issue on that.

Comment: Usually if you managed to log in with the credentials that means that credentials are good. So your issue should be solved.

Any update on the matter?